# Using 'audio' and only JS and CSS (without libraries) create 2 audio player styles by setting class

Tags: javascript, html, css, audio

I would like to create 2 different audio players, 1 large and 1 small. I would like to be able to set which one to display directly in the HTML by setting a class.

The large one should have a play/pause button icon and progress bar that will take up it's own line on a webpage. The small one only a play button icon (using SVG) that toggles based on the current state (playing or paused) that can be displayed inline on a webpage.

This is the HTML I would ideally like to be able to use:

```
<audio class="small">
  <source src="mysound.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="mysound.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

I have been playing around with it, this is the closest I have been able to get:

```
<div class="audio">
   <audio id="player" src="mysound.mp3"></audio>
   <a id="button" title="button">Play</a>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  var playing = false;

  $('a#button').click(function() {
      $(this).toggleClass("down");

      if (playing == false) {
          document.getElementById('player').play();
          playing = true;
          $(this).text("Pause");

      } else {
        document.getElementById('player').pause();
        playing = false;
        $(this).text("Play");
      }
  });
});
</script>
```

There are several issues with the above code:

1. Once the audio finishes playing "Pause" does not toggle back to
   display "Play".
2. If there are multiple players on the page it doesn't
   target `this`.
3. It's clunky and requires the person writing the page
   to add lots of code. I would like to move most of this to JS and
   CSS.

I feel that I'm on entirely the wrong track, but I can't find good documentation for making this simpler.